# $X,Y\subset\mathbb{R}$ with $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$ continuous and bijective but not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Consider the following two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology:
> \begin{align*}
>     X&=(0,1)\cup\{2\}\cup (3,4)\cup\{5\}\cup\cdots\cup (3n,3n+1)\cup\{3n+2\}\cup\ldots\\
>     Y&=(0,1]\cup\{2\}\cup(3,4)\cup\{5\}\cup\cdots\cup (3n,3n+1)\cup\{3n+2\}\cup\ldots
> \end{align*}
> (a) Provide two bijective continuous functions $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$.
>
> (b) Prove that $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic.

I've been looking at this for a while now, and I think I have discovered $f$:
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 
     x & x\in (3n,3n+1),\;n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\},\\
     1 & x=2,\\
     3(n-1)+2 & x=3n+2,\;n\in\mathbb{N}.
   \end{cases}
$$
This should be continuous on $X$ since it is simply the identity function on intervals and elsewhere the isolated points are mapped to isolated points so it is continuous there.

The problem is I don't know how to find $g$. I can't figure out a way for $1$ to map to something without break continuity. I haven't thought much about the second part, but I feel like it could be justified by coming up with some property which is preserved under homeomorphisms that $X$ and $Y$ do not share.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From $Y$ to $X$, you can use the fact that $(0,1)=\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\cup \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$.

Comment: Define $g(x)=\frac12x$ for $x\in(0,1]$ and $g(x)=\frac12x-1$ for $x\in (3,4)$.

Comment: $Y$ has an infinite component with a non-cut point. $X$ has not.

Comment: Understood. Thanks everyone. I'll compile the comments together and submit an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Set
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 
     x & x\in (3n,3n+1),\;n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\\
     1 & x=2\\
     3(n-1)+2 & x=3n+2,\;n\in\mathbb{N}.
   \end{cases}
$$
On $\{x\in (3n,3n+1)\,:\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, $f$ is simply the identity, so it is continuous at these points. The other points in the domain are isolated points, so the function is continuous there as well. This shows that $f$ is continuous.

Now, set
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
x/2 & x\in (0,1)\\
(x-3)/2+1/2 & x\in (3,4)\\
x & x=3n+2,\;n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\\
x-3 & x\in (3n,3n+1),\; n\in\mathbb{N}
\end{cases}.
$$
This function is a piecewise gluuing of continuous functions on the connected components on $Y$, so it is continuous.

(b) Note that $1\in Y$ cut point: a point whose removal causes the creation of two connected pieces, while $X$ has no such points. This is a property preserved by homeomorphisms, so a homeomorphism cannot exist.