# $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ are bijective and continuous. Then two metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces.
Suppose that there is a mapping $f:X\to Y$ which is bijective and continuous.
Suppose that there is a mapping $g:Y\to X$ which is bijective and continuous.
Then, are $X$ and $Y$ homeomorphic?

Comment: No, as shown by some of the answers to my similar question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/30661/2060).

Comment: Also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2320644/4280).

Comment: Henno Brandsma, Thank you very much for your comments.